# Зная номер столбца двумерного массива пройтись по каждой строке этого столбца и определить, есть ли в нем вводимое значение Java

Tags: java, динамические-массивы

Считываю с документа строки и записываю их в двумерный массив

```
    int arrWidth = Matrix.size();
    int arrLength = Matrix.get(0).size();
    String [][] array = new String[arrWidth][arrLength];

    for(int y = 0; y < Matrix.size(); y++){
       for(int x = 0; x < Matrix.get(y).size(); x++){
          array[y][x] = (String)Matrix.get(y).get(x);
       }
    }
```

Тут пытаюсь пройти по 0-ому столбцу и сравнить значения с 1815, но ничего не компилится

```
    for(int i = 0; i<array[0].length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<array.length; j++){
            if(array[0][j].equals("1815")){
            System.out.print(array[0][j] + " ");
        }

}
```

Comment: что не компилится? приведите текст ошибки

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
1815 1815 1815  at readarray.ReadArray.getArrayFromFile(ReadArray.java:42)
 at readarray.ReadArray.main(ReadArray.java:64)

Comment: Что находится в 64 строке ReadArray.java? Добавьте текст с ошибкой и код, в которой она возникает в вопрос.

Comment: обращаюсь к методу, где весь код лежит. в том числе и считывание с файла

Comment: Судя по всему, проблема именно в считывании из файла, но без кода никакой конкретики не сказать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Тут пытаюсь пройти по 0-ому столбцу и сравнить значения с 1815, но ничего не компилится

Если вам нужен только 1й столбец каждой строки, то нет необходимости итерироваться по столбцам, достаточно:

```
for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
    if ("1815".equals(array[j][0])) {
        System.out.print(array[j][0] + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, так почти получилось. Только нужно 0 и j местами поменять. array[j][0] j-строка, 0 - столбец.

Comment: @YulkaBogdan Поменял